# Nodejs change the bot's nickname every time the variable change DISOCRD.JS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm doing a dominance ticker for bitcoin and I want to show the price in the nickname of the bot, the thing is that I don't know why but I can't change the nickname, it throws me an error.

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();
const request = require("request");
var LastBitcoinDominance = 100;

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
})


myFunction()
function myFunction() {

    const url = "API";

    request(url, (err, res, body) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(body);


        var bitcoinDominance = data.bitcoin_dominance_percentage;

        if (bitcoinDominance == LastBitcoinDominance){
            console.log("Bitcoin dominance and LastBitcoinDominacne are the same")
        }else {
            client.user.setUsername(bitcoinDominance)
            LastBitcoinDominance = bitcoinDominance;
        }
    });

    setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);
}
client.login(TOKEN)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because client could not be detected. Because `null` means literally **nothing**.

Try using:

```js
client.login(TOKEN);
```

instead of:

```js
client.token(TOKEN);
```

Edit:

Try this:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();
const request = require("request");
var LastBitcoinDominance = 100;

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
})


myFunction(client)
function myFunction(client) {

    const url = "API";

    request(url, (err, res, body) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(body);


        var bitcoinDominance = data.bitcoin_dominance_percentage;

        if (bitcoinDominance == LastBitcoinDominance){
            console.log("Bitcoin dominance and LastBitcoinDominacne are the same")
        }else {
            client.user.setUsername(bitcoinDominance);
            LastBitcoinDominance = bitcoinDominance;
        }
    });

    setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);
}
client.login(TOKEN)
```

I added a parameter to your function `myFunction`, because you cannot use your client inside a function. Therefor you provide it for the parameter `client`. Inside the function the parameter `client` is now your client, because you provided it.

Comment: The bot logins perfect, cause it is on in the server, but it crashes automatically when the bot changes the username

Comment: @JuanBadal edited my answer. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the bot has permissions.
i tried running this and i didn't get any errors:
[image: code]

Comment: It does not look like a permission problem in the image, It would have said something about being unauthorized/invalid permissions. Currently, he is attempting to use a function that has likely been deprecated in the discord.js.org docs.

Comment: The problem is that, also I cant change the setPresence and to change the setPresence I dont need any permission